# Audio amp distortion

Tags: audio, amplifier

I am attempting to repair the amplifier stage of a Harmon kardon 1970's vintage stereo. The right channel is fine but the left exhibits extreme distortion. I fed a sine wave in and can see that the entire negative half of the waveform is being clipped (except for a slight 'ripple' at the beginning). This only happens under load (speaker connected). Any thoughts on where to look?

Comment: Do you have the model number and/or schematic?

Comment: 330c (the service manual found online has the schematic)

Comment: general electronics repair advice: check electrolytic capacitors for bulging or leaking tops. Probably the most likely component to fail in any circuit.

Comment: @PhilFrost - excellent advice, also a good ESR meter that can test in circuit is a great tool to have handy (for the not-so-obvious ones)

Comment: Not sure why this one got closed - is debugging a problem not part of electronic design? I think it could end up with some useful information if left to run it's course...

Comment: Your question was closed as off topic, likely because it's asked with regard to one particular make and model of amp. Could you edit a schematic into the question or could you try to ask in a more general way ("How is this type of clipping possible with a class AB audio amp"), ideally including a schematic or some scope screenshots? Then, your question will be helpful for others and I will be happy to vote for re-opening.

Answer (score 5):

Check the negative supply rail to the channel, the bias level to the output transistors and the transistors themselves.
If you follow the signal from the input with a scope, you should come to a point where it goes bad, then you narrow down your suspect components.

Also, tapping gently with a plastic implement around the board whist observing the wave can provide some useful information sometimes (connectors/wiring included in case of bad contacts)

Comment: The signal goes bad almost immediately, but I replaced the transistors in that area to no effect.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm out and on my phone at present, will have a look at the schematic and update with any thoughts in an hour or two.

Comment: Okay, found the [service manual](http://akdatabase.org/AKview/albums/userpics/10004/Harman%20Kardon%20330c%20Service.pdf) - having a browse around the circuit now. Any measurements you have taken (e.g. signal level used, voltage of rails, point where distortion starts, etc) might come in handy if possible (both with and without load present)

Comment: Also which input you are using (phono, tape, aux)

Comment: I was using aux input so I could view a simple sine wave from a generator. All voltages were close to the the ones shown in the service manual until just before the final power amp. There instead of -27v, I was getting closer to -25 or lower based on volume level (Higher volume and voltage would continue to drop toward 0).

Comment: Actually, Looking at the sine wave on my scope again... it very much looks like clipping, but the negative rail is just fine. and the issues are only on the one channel.